# Strange issue regarding MVC login when published to live server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8, asp.net-identity-2

I have a basic MVC project which I have published to a remote server.  It loads correctly but for some reason there is a seemingly random issue regarding logging in, using the default mvc identity system.

Yesterday when I tested it on Firefox/Chrome/Edge it logged in fine on Chrome but took forever to login on Firefox and Edge and eventually timed out.  Later I tried it at home on a different computer and all 3 browsers worked fine.  Today I try it and Chrome has the issue but Edge and Firefox work.  Today when I try it on my friends computer it works in Chrome but not Edge or Firefox.

I don't understand what could be the problem.  The database is on one server, the site is hosted on another.  If I run the project locally but with the connection to the remote server it works just fine on all browsers all of the time.

The server uses iis 8, I presume I must have configured something incorrectly.  Can anyone shed any light on what I might be doing wrong?

Worth noting that I am using Applicationdbcontext for all of my models, one context in one database.

Also, project is running in release mode.

Comment: Best guess is that there is some inefficient code in your login action method that is amplified by the network latency of using separate physical servers. Please post the code related to the slowness.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment but I've discovered the issue is that the project runs perfectly on the slave server but not the master.  I should have mentioned two servers were involved, the load balancer meant that when accessing the site it would sometimes load from the master and sometimes from the slave.  I'm not puzzling over what could be making the difference on the master as the project is identical and the iis settings are copied from master to slave.